# i want to select records based on a field which was not present for the past 2 months

Tags: mysql

Consider two table **Transaction** and **Customer**.
i want to select records of the customers who haven't done transactions for the last 2 months.

**Transaction** contains

> From_CustomerId

**Customer** contains

> CustomerId, email

*From_CustomerId* is the only foreign key between them and i want to select

> email

with time range for the last two months.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Transaction contains any date fields? or the user have any dates...with out that there is no way to achieve this as you cant compare time days dates and now, why would you have transactions without the date of the transaction

Comment: yes "date" is the field name

Comment: than just compare dates till now same as you compare id to user..you should have mention that...lol as that is important

Answer (score 1):

You can do as

```
select 
c.* from Customer c
left join Transaction t on t.From_CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
and t.date between curdate()-interval 2 month and curdate() 
where t.From_CustomerId is null
```

Comment: what does t and c are

Comment: aliases for the tables transaction, and customer, respectively

Comment: They are just alias for table names and lazy people like me always use them so that I do not have to write the tablename again in the query and use the alias name.